# What should I learn to become good front-end developer?

Tags: frontend

I have learn the basic HTML & CSS and now I am in the process of learning JavaScript. So what should I learn next to become good front-end developer that have big percentage hired by a company. Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For frontend development, all you need to get started with is learn some basic HTML, CSS, and JavaScript and start working on projects; everything else you will learn along the way. Don't learn everything in a parallel manner. **learn less, code more**. when you used to code then you will be able to choose your desire and comfort stack soon. [here](https://roadmap.sh/frontend) is a big picture of the frontend road map. But you didn't need to learn everything here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer that was quick. I have seen the roadmap you gave me, I will learn based on that roadmap. Thank you.

Comment: glad to help @AdeAprianto